# LINQ in MVC Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have written a working MVC web app.  I started using SQL statements back to the DB, but have changed to LINQ.  I have a view that shows all work in the IT department and a button to allow the user to select tasks allocated to them.

I am trying to get the IT workers list from the model list of files, like this

```
{@IEnumerable<@AERS_WEB.Models.clsFileDetails> fls = @Model.FILES.Where(q=>q.DEVELOPER=="ac")}
```

but I get an error

> Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' requires 1 type arguments

I've also tried

```
{@List<@AERS_WEB.Models.clsFileDetails> fls = @Model.FILES.Where(q=>q.DEVELOPER=="ac")}
{@IList<@AERS_WEB.Models.clsFileDetails> fls = @Model.FILES.Where(q=>q.DEVELOPER=="ac")}
```

Comment: I'd really stress not accessing the database directly from a View. That violates the purpose of the MVC architecture. Instead create a method in your Model (or better: ViewModel) called GetWorkers() that returns a List<whatever>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@{
    IEnumerable<AERS_WEB.Models.clsFileDetails> fls =
        Model.FILES.Where(q=>q.DEVELOPER=="ac").ToList();
 }
```

Although it seems that `AERS_WEB.Models.clsFileDetails` is not a type.

Try to think of it like:

```
IEnumerable<int> = new List<int>();
```

or

```
IEnumerable<SomeClass> = new List<SomeClass>();
```

By the way, keep in mind that it's bad habbit to query a database from a view, it disturbs the MVC pattern.

And make sure that `Model.FILES.Where(q=>q.DEVELOPER=="ac")` returns items of type: `AERS_WEB.Models.clsFileDetails`.

Comment: clsFileDetails is a class, which the model list FILES is also a list of.  The return will be clsFileDetails.  Your code worked fine.  Many thanks

Comment: Out of interest, how do i get my view to use the filtered list instead of the model?           @if(@ViewBag.DEVELOPERONLY)
        {
            showFiles=developersFiles;
        }
        else
        {
            showFiles = Model.FILES;
        }

        @foreach (AERS_WEB.Models.clsFileDetails f in showFiles)